# Xamarin Forms: Navigation stack has wrong order

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my navigation stack.

I have three pages and in the first one I have a PushAsync to the second page in the OnAppearing Trigger. The second page has a PushAsync to the third page in the constructor.

So this is what the stack should look like:

Page1 > Page2 > Page3

However, the stack looks like this

Page1 > Page3 > Page2

So my question is, do you call pushasync in constructor or don't do it.
I'm still at the beginning so I don't know what to do and what not to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give await operator in Constructor So to obtain result you can do as this.

```
  Public Constructor()
    {
    Doit();
    }

    public async void Doit()
    {
    // In fisrt page insert second page.. 
    //In second page too do the same while inserting third Page
    await await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourPage());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely not awaiting the Push Methods, that's why you can have a wrong order in your Navigation Stack:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourPage());
```